# PHP 4.4 undefined index errors from $_POST when accessing through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, captcha

I'm trying to use recaptcha with PHP and AJAX and I'm stuck. For some reason whenever I try to take something out of $_POST I get an error message.

I'm running PHP 4.4.

```
<?php  

require_once('includes/recaptchalib.php');  
define("PRIV_KEY", "yesthereisakeyhere");  

$name = $_POST['name'];  // This line comes back as undefined index 
$email = $_POST['email'];  //This line comes back as undefined index 

if(in_array('', array($name, $email))) {  
//one (or more) of the required fields is empty  
$result = "field_error";  
} else {  
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (PRIV_KEY, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);  // 2 more undefined index errors here. 
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {  
     //Captcha was entered incorrectly  
  $result = "captcha_error";  
   } else {  
     //Captcha was entered correctly  
     $result = "success";  
     //mail function goes in here.
 }  
}  

echo $result;  
?>
```

This is my HTML for reference:

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/recaptchalib.php');
    define("PUB_KEY", "yesthereisakeyhere");  
?>
<form class="form" method="post">     
    <label>Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="required" />
    <label>Email *</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="required" />

    <?php echo recaptcha_get_html(PUB_KEY); ?>  

    <input type="submit" value="GET A QUOTE" />
</form>
```

Here is a my AJAX call for reference:

```
$("#locator-quote input[type=submit]").click(function() {            
        $(".message").removeClass("success").removeClass("error").addClass("loader").html("Sending message").fadeIn("slow");  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "ajax.php",  
                data: $(this).serialize(),  
                dataType: 'text',  
                success: function(msg){
                $('body').prepend('<h1>' + msg + '</h1>')  /// This line is for testing
                switch(msg) {

                case "field_error": // one or more fields is/are empty  
                    $(".message").removeClass("loader").addClass("error");  
                    $(".message").html("Please fill in all the required fields.");  
                    break;  
                case "captcha_error": // captcha wasn't typed correctly  
                    $(".message").removeClass("loader").addClass("error");  
                    $(".message").html("Please type the words correctly and try again!");  
                    break;  
                case "success": // all good  
                    $(".message").removeClass("loader").addClass("success");  
                    $(".message").html("Your message has been sent. You'll soon hear from us!");  
                    break;  
                default: // Hmm. The default case. You never know.  
                alert("Something is wrong. Please try again.");  
                    }  
                }  
            });  
            Recaptcha.reload();  
            return false;  
        });
```

Comment: Are you *really* using PHP4?

Comment: This site was built by someone else and for some reason they never updated

Comment: Didn't `$_POST` not exist in PHP4?  Maybe you need `$HTTP_POST_VARS`?

Comment: It was introduced in version 4.1 according to the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to serialize the button and not the form.

You are listening to the `$("#locator-quote input[type=submit]").click` event, so `this` will be the button.

You need to serialize the form.

```
$(this).closest('form').serialize()
```

Or, instead bind to the form's `.submit` event.

```
$('.form').submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem